# How to count table column categoryname in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

working with Laravel 5.6 and mysql. I have following table name as **vehicles**

```
id  name  number   type  
1   def   123      Car
2   lki   589      Van
3   loi   256      Truck
4   oiu   569      Car
5   hyy   589      Van
```

Now I need count number of each type columns values I do not wanna loop count. just I need count each Type and show on blade file. like this,

```
Car 2
Van 2
Truck 1
```

etc.. how can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply `Group By` on the `type` column, and use [`Count(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct) to count the number of rows:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM vehicles  
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Since OP mentioned `Laravel` in the tags, probably he will need it in form of `Laravel Eloquent` or using `DB` facade syntax.

Comment: I am going to print this data in my sidebar blade file then my sidebar blade file is in the following path '_includes.nav.usermenu' so, then how can I make route for this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$vehiclesInfo = DB::table('vehicles')
                 ->select('type', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('type')
                 ->get();
```

For more info on group by and count you can follow this tutorial.
[Larvel queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)

Comment: I am going to print this data in my sidebar blade file then my sidebar blade file is in the following path '_includes.nav.usermenu' so, then how can I make route for this?

Comment: This is separate question. Please mark this one as accepted if it helps you and post another question :)

Comment: I dont know wether is this work or not because my blade file got following errors **Undefined variable: $vehiclesInfo**

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DB` facade to get count with groupby

```
$vehicles= DB::table('vehicles')
                 ->select('type', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                 ->groupBy('type')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: I am going to print this data in my sidebar blade file then my sidebar blade file is in the following path '_includes.nav.usermenu' so, then how can I make route for this?